# Matching similar strings in MySQL / PHP

Tags: php, mysql, string, string-matching

I am working on a system which allows users to create media listings. I'm attempting to match the names and group repeated items but retain the original name for the user. My issue is how to accurately match similar names. For example, if I have:

"Harry Potter and the philosophers stone"
"The philosophers stone - Harry Potter"
"Harry Potter - the philosophers stone"

How can I match those 3 in a MySQL database? Is there any query I can use to do this or perhaps another technology that I would need to incorporate to do it?

Comment: This is interesting question... But just imagine what will be the results for: 1) "Harry Potter", 2) "Harry philosophers stone", 3) "Harry Potter and the stone", 4) "Michael Jackson and the philosophers stone", 5) "Potter the stone and Harry philosophers" - which of these options match "Harry Potter and the philosophers stone"?

Comment: Do you want to do this compare automatically or manually create links between different naming options?

Comment: I'm hoping to automatically create the links however I understand that some manual confirmation may be required, especially in the case of "Michael Jackson and the philosophers stone" and anything that may be similar but not the same. I just need to find a way to catch the majority and perhaps prompt for user confirmation.

Comment: This is called 'fuzzy matching' and is a big topic in the world of text analytics. There are lots of different algorythms out there with different levels of complexity and different advantages / disadvantages. Some simpler ones (e.g. levenshtein distance) can be implemented in mysql, but the more complex ones require  a proper programming language. Most of these algorithms are implemented in python or R, not really in php. You need to research the algorithms and pick the one that best suits your business case.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to define how to understand if 2 strings are "similar". What is the measure of "similarity"?

And while you are thinking about that, I can remember one build-in function in PHP: `similar_text`. Here is example: [click](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/f0e5367e2defbf97a55b9fbbaa85edd256ba62eb).

Code:

```php
$str = [
    "Harry Potter and the philosophers stone",
    "The philosophers stone - Harry Potter",
    "Harry Potter - the philosophers stone"
];

for ($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i++) {
    echo "[" . $i . "] " . $str[$i] . "\n";
}
for ($i = 0; $i < count($str); $i++) {
    for ($j = $i + 1; $j < count($str); $j++) {
        $value = similar_text($str[$i], $str[$j], $p);
        echo "[" . $i . "] VS [" . $j . "] = " . $value . " (" . $p . " %)\n";
    }
}
```

Gives us this result:

```
[0] Harry Potter and the philosophers stone
[1] The philosophers stone - Harry Potter
[2] Harry Potter - the philosophers stone
[0] VS [1] = 21 (55.263157894737 %)
[0] VS [2] = 36 (94.736842105263 %)
[1] VS [2] = 21 (56.756756756757 %)
```

You can see that "Harry Potter and the philosophers stone" and "Harry Potter - the philosophers stone" is 94% similar.

I can only recommend you to read this PHP manual: [click](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php) with all the comments below.

P.S. There are another 2 functions in PHP: `levenshtein` and `soundex`. You can check them by yourself. They are also mentioned on [manual page](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.similar-text.php).

Answer (score -1):

perhaps have three different fields in your database, Each with the string name as above, but give them a unique identifier as a number.

Comment: Not sure I understand. These are just examples and many more could be entered that should link to the same thing. I have no problem linking them, it's about matching them in first place to create the link.